# Check for Insert Failure Due to Page Lock

Tags: sap-ase

I freely admit that I know nothing about sybase in terms of its return codes. My experience has primarily been with Oracle and SQL Server. This particular project requires an insert into a binary field of a table that periodically fails because the entry is locked. Looking at the code it doesn't appear that I am able to successfully detect a lock condition. My current strategy is to insert the data, then select and determine if the insert was successful, and retry if it was not using threads that sleep for several seconds in between retry attempts. This fails to account for other data that may have altered the entry prior to my original data insert and may be more current than the data that I am attempting to insert. Is there a simple way to determine if the row is locked before attempting an insert, wait for the lock to clear, then lock the row myself before an insert? Alternately, if I can detect that the entry is locked, then I can fail the transaction and alert the user to the failure so that it can be manually inspected. Before anyone asks, I am unable to change the architecture of the RDMS in terms of how it is set up to lock entries. This has to be handled by the code that performs the insert.

Comment: `LOCK TABLE <<table>> IN EXCLUSIVE MODE NOWAIT` will try to acquire exclusive lock on your table. check for `@@error != 0` if it fails to do so

Answer (score 1):

Locking the entire table will work, but is pretty crude if you're only looking for smaller granularity of a page (as per the title of your question).
You can actually do that by doing SET LOCK NOWAIT before the INSERT and then checking @@ERROR for status code 12205 which indicates there was a lock on something that was needed in order to do the insert. Don't forget to run SET LOCK WAIT to restore the default or NOWAIT will apply to the rest of your session.

Comment: Nice, didn't know you could specify it globally for a session and that too they will use their own locking mechanism.. Nice!!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    LOCK TABLE <<table_name>>
        IN EXCLUSIVE MODE NOWAIT

    IF @@error != 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        PRINT 'COULD NOT ACQUIRE LOCK. EXITING ...'
        RETURN 0
    END

    << your code here if it was able to lock >>

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: I am unfamilar with sybase, but doesn't it seem a little overkill to have to lock the entire table in order to attempt to detect that a single record would be prevented from being updated/inserted?